# Is Python good for writing standard, compatible and complete SOAP web services?

Tags: c#, python, soap, twisted

I have used few python soap libraries (**SOAPpy, soaplib and Twisted wrapper around SOAPpy**) to write my soap web service.

When I used python clients (SOAPpy.SOAPProxy and SUDS), I was able to communicate with my web service (returning simple and complex type objects).

But, when I tried with C# ASP.net, I got many issues. I came over returning simple types (int, string, double, boolean) issue with some hack into SOAPpy library. **But, I am still struggling with returning ComplexTypes from SOAPpy.**

I could not find any complete, compatible alternative python library for writing my web service.

**Main Question:** Any suggestions/examples for dot net compatible complex type return from python web service would be highly appreciated.

Note: *I had to hack SOAPpy quite a bit to make it working in first place. And, I had to handwrite wsdl file in case of SOAPpy.*

Comment: I haven't tried it but you may want to check out http://pywebsvcs.sourceforge.net/zsi.html

Comment: what data does server return?

Comment: @(James Black) zsi is part of same family of library as of SOAPpy. But, I will look into the code, if zsi has newer version of SOAPpy in it.

@(PirosB3) - My server in few of api functions return complex type (python list of dictionary, e.g. [{'field_1':'value1','field_2':'value2'},{'field_1':'value3','field_2':'value4'}].

Comment: I believe SOAPpy development was abandoned in favour of ZSI; although, last time I looked, there was not much ZSI development activity either. suds is the only actively-developed SOAP library for Python that I've seen recently.

Comment: @mithrandi As per my knowledge, SOAPpy code has been carried over to ZSI. SUDS is good client library, it does not have server implementation support. I recently joined python mailing list for soap at http://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/soap people were discussing soaplib there and they are aware of inter-compatibility issues in soaplib.

Comment: With my recent python soap mailing list conversation http://code.google.com/p/pysimplesoap/ works well for returning complex types for dot net clients. I still need to integrate this into python twisted library to make better use of it. If someone is already working on it, I am happy to collaborate. But my question is still open about python as a language to be 100% soap compatible with other libraries in other languages.

Answer (score 1):

In my personal opinion, the compatibility of Python SOAP libraries with other platforms is not good.

I think that there are two issues here:

- First, the compatibility of web services among web service stacks is an aspiration rather than reality. For example, look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690177/guaranteeing-that-a-net-wcf-service-can-be-consumed-by-a-java-client) to see how to use web services between Java and WCF.
- That being said, the concept of WSDL which is largely compile time typing is not in line with Python's original philosophy, so less effort was put into it.

I haven't worked with web services for over a year now so may be things have changed. But the advice is the same as in the previous question:

- Start with the WSDL writing if you are using more than one language/library.
- As copied from the other question, "start with XSD, but confine yourself to mainstream types. Primitives, complextypes composed of primitives, arrays of same."
- In the end I settled on using `suds` for Python web clients, after experimenting with it and `soappy` and `zsi`. That was after some time using a C based library [(gsoap)](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html) and linking to it from Python.
- I was never satisfied with server implementations in Python, so I used to build Python servers and connect to them from another library which can export SOAP services (in my case Java or C, you will probably use C#). The connection is usually a much simpler protocol.
- That being said, if you start with WSDL you are likely to get good results using `soaplib` or may be `zsi`. But I am afraid there is almost no way around building your types slowly while checking for compatibility.

Comment: Due to some technical complexity of my project, I have to write my web service in Python only. But, client could come from any language. For python, SOAPpy.SOAPProxy client works fine, but I am concerned about c# and java. I have handwritten my wsdl file to make sure, I use primitive types and complex types made up of primitive types. But, SOAPpy returns list as follows:

<result SOAP-ENC:arrayType="ns1:SOAPStruct[3]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" xmlns:ns1="http://soapinterop.org/xsd" SOAP-ENC:root="0" id="i3">.......

Can you point me complex type return example from SOAPpy & consumed by dot net